# Stuck At project in c

Tags: c, file, structure

Hi guys so i have to do a project for my programming class, i have to create a file with code of travels and its destinations if the code already exists i have to update it with new information. I tried to do it but for some reason my program keeps crashing at the end of the while.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int patente;
    float fecha;
    char dest[40];
    int cant;
}viajes;

FILE * abrir();
void main(void)
{
FILE * pf;
pf=abrir();
viajes viajes,vaux;

    printf("Ingrese Numero de patete: ");
    scanf("%d",&viajes.patente);
    fflush(stdin);
    while (viajes.patente!=0)
    {
        printf("Ingrese Fecha: ");
        scanf("%f",&viajes.fecha);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Destino: ");
        gets(viajes.dest);
        fflush(stdin);
        fseek(pf,0L,SEEK_END);
            if ( ftell(pf) == 0 )
            {
            viajes.cant=1;
            fwrite(&viajes,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);
            }
            else
            {
                fseek(pf,0L,SEEK_SET);
                fread(&vaux,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);
                while(!feof(pf)&&vaux.patente!=viajes.patente)
                {
                    fread(&vaux,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);
                if(feof(pf))
                {
                    viajes.cant=1;
                    fwrite(&viajes,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);
                }
                else
                {
                    fseek(pf,(-1L)*sizeof(viajes),SEEK_CUR);
                    vaux.cant++;
                    strcpy(vaux.dest,viajes.dest);
                    vaux.fecha=viajes.fecha;
                    fwrite(&vaux,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);
                }
                }

            }

    printf("Ingrese Numero de patete: ");
    scanf("%d",&viajes.patente);
    fflush(stdin);
    }
    fseek(pf,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&viajes,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);//lee un registro
    puts("Patente \t Fecha \t Destino \t Viajes");
    while(!feof(pf))
        {
            fread(&viajes,sizeof(viajes),1,pf);
            printf("\n%d \t %f \t %s \t %d",viajes.patente,viajes.fecha,viajes.dest,viajes.cant);
        }
    fclose(pf);
}

FILE * abrir(void)
{

    FILE * pf;
    pf = fopen("infcamion.jp","r+b");
    if(pf==NULL)
    {
        pf= fopen("infocamion.jp","w+b");
        if(pf==NULL)
        {
            perror("infocl.jp");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    return pf;
}
```

EDIT: i posted the full code, i can compile it with no warnings or errors program is crashing on the second batch of information i gave

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*. Do not use it.

Comment: `gets()` has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun. You shouldn't use it.

Comment: `scanf("%d",viajes.patente);` invokes *undefined behavior* for passing data having wrong type.

Comment: You don't show all of the outer `while` loop.  If that's the loop that's crashing, add the rest of the code.

Comment: There is no need to use the `feof()` function to control a `fread()` loop (even when  correctly implemented). The way to do it is by checking the return value from `fread`. When it is `0` you have read all of the file. `while((itemsread = fread(...)) != 0) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably `scanf("%d",viajes.patente);`.  You need to pass pointers to `scanf`, not integers.  Make sure that you compile your code with all warnings enabled and your compiler should flag things like this.

Comment: oh yes i fixed it, but is still crashing